# The set of continuous functions is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of bounded functions on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Note that $d(f,g) = \sup|f(t) − g(t)|$. If $A\subset X$ is the set of continuous functions on $[a, b]$, show that $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Can you please also show that (X,d) is complete?

Comment: Note that, uniform convergence preserves continuity.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset A\;\;,\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=:f \;\;\text{exists}\iff$$

$$d(f_n,f):=\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f_n(t)-f(t)|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\iff f_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f\;\;\text{uniformly}\;\ldots$$